# Reducing a matrix using similarity transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to reduce a matrix to an Upper Hessenberg form with similarity transformations. I figured that the Householder Method would be the way to solve this problem, but I'm having problems with the linear algebra of this method.

The part where I'm having trouble is in the calculation of H1. My equation is:

H1=I-2*((v1*v1^T)/(v1^T*v1)),

Where "V1^T" is the transpose of V1

When I am doing this calculation by hand (we're not allowed to use MATLAB), the top and bottom of the right hand size division always turns into 1. Basically I'm getting: v1*v1^T=v1^T*v1

Am I doing something wrong? Is my equation wrong?

I'm working with the following matrix:

A = [-3 3 7 2; 1 2 3 -5; 2 -1 0 3; 4 2 -2 4]

Thank you!

-- EDITED INFO BELOW --

I got past the multiplication issue, but I'm encountering a different issue now. I wrote the following code based on lecture notes and an example, and the code works fine for the one example. However, for my matrix, the first application of the transformation does not turn any of the elements into 0. I must be missing something.

```
A_0=[-3 3 7 2;1 2 3 -5;2 -1 0 3; 4 2 -2 4];
e1=[1;0;0;0];
v1=A_0(:,1)-(sign(A_0(1,1)))*norm(A_0(:,1))*e1;
I=eye(length(v1));
H1=I-2*((v1*transpose(v1))/(transpose(v1)*v1));
A_1=A_0-0.5*v1*transpose(v1)*A_0;
```

Comment: if $v$ is $ 4 \times 1$ column vector, $vv^T$ is a $4 \times 4$ rank one matrix and $v^Tv$ is the length of $v$ squares, a positive number. how can $v^Tv = vv^T$ unless $v$ is just a number? what you need to is you  can find a householder reflection matrix $H$ that sends any vector $v$ to $|v|e_1$ where $e_1$ has $1$ for the first component and $0$ for all others. $H$ is constructed by picking the direction of the bisector $u = v + !v|e_1$ and forming $H = 2uu^T/(u^Tu) - I.$ after one application you can partition $HA$ into $|v|,$ row vector, column vector, and a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: Hi Abel, yes your observation was correct that I was simply doing the math incorrectly. However I think I have something else missing in my code, based on the fact that the elements below the 1st have not turned into 0 after the first transformation is applied. See above for details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what you do is you find a $3 \times 3$ reflection matrix $q_1 = 2uu^T/u^Tu - I,$ where $u = (1\ 2\ 4)^T + (\sqrt{21}\ 0 \ 0)^T.$ this gives $R_1(1\ 2\ 4)^T = (\sqrt{21}\ 0\ 0)^T.$  partition your matrix $a_1 = [-3|3\ 7\ 2],[1\ 2\ 4]^T| a_2].$
form a $4 \times 4$ orthogonal matrix $q1 =[1|0\ 0\ 0],[0\ 0\ 0]^T| R_1].$ now,
$q_1 a_1 q_1$ should have zeros in the first column below the sub diagonal(i.e. 31
41 elements are zero). you can iterate this to reduce your matrix to upper hessenberg form

for more details on this, you can refer to page 342, section 7.4.2 of matrix computations by golub and van loan, 3rd edition.